# What is a cost map and where is it created?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros navigation possible without a cost map?

Where are costmaps made at?

navigation global plan make it?

Is the planning data of the costmap a coordinate value?

Is it the coordinate value of the map frame reference?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347361/what-is-a-cost-map-and-where-is-it-created?/) by [mywjdp@naver.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/52779/mywjdp@naver.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2020-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a large body of documentation here: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation

Costmap docs: http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d

Here's a paper on the specific-to-ROS-navigation costmap implementation: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6942636

Here's the navigation stack paper from way-back-when: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5509725

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-03-24**:
If this gave you the required resources -- can you mark as correct so its off our queue?

**Comment by [mywjdp@naver.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/52779/mywjdp@naver.com/) on 2020-03-24**:
Thank you.